# Objective C - incompatible integer to pointer conversion

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to iOS programming.

I am getting an `"Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSString *'"` error when I try and run the following code:

```
- (IBAction)oneToSix {
    int rNumber = arc4random() % 6;
    [result setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: rNumber]];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert the `int` to a `NSString` before sending it to the `imageNamed` method.  This is because `imageNamed` takes a `NSString` as the argument and not an `int`.  Try this:

```
- (IBAction)oneToSix {
    int rNumber = arc4random() % 6;
    [result setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rNumber]]];
}
```

More info here: [UIImage Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `imageNamed:` takes an `NSString` as input, not an `int`. To fix this, just convert the `int` into an `NSString` by

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rNumber]
```